# Auto generate id number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a library management system. I want to generate different book code for different book genre. For eg:- There is a combo box with book three book genres(novel,literature,poem) and there is another text box with book code. I want if someone chooses novel in comboBox, book code starts form N001 and if someone chooses literature in comboBox, book code starts from L001 and if someone chooses poem, book code starts from P001.
(My vb application is connected with ms access database.)

Comment: Simply let the database assign unique ID numbers with an auto-number field. Add a column for your genre code.

Comment: You might want to check out the Dewey Decimal Classification system for some ideas.

Comment: I manage a library system. This isn't how they work. You use the library of congress or dewey classification systems to create call numbers. Otherwise, you have accession numbers, which are just identity fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several schools of thought on how one can approach this.
One way? Well, you say have a book type or some such, and then you have that book code. It would be a simple number column without the prefix (P, B etc.).

So, to get the next number, you would then go:

```
myBookNumber = DMAX("BookNumber","tblBooks","BookType = 'P')
MyBookNumber = MyBookNumber + 1
```

So, you simply store the book number separate from the prefix. In forms, reports etc., you can then always display the book number like rst!BookType & rst!BookNumber

Another way, which I prefer is to create a table that allows you to get the next book number This also makes it easy to add more types, and better is such a design lets you set the starting number. This approach is also often used for invoice numbers.

So, you create a table called tlbBookIncrements. It will look like this:

```
ID: (pk - autonumber)
BookType:  text (the one char book type)  
BookNumber: Number the next book number to assign.
```

You then build a function like this:

```
Public Function GetNextBookN(strBookType As String) As Long

  Dim strSQL     As String
  Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblBookIncrement where BookType = '" & strBookType & "'"
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
  If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
     ' this book type does not exist - lets add it and start at 1
     rst.AddNew
     rst!BookType = strBookType
     rst!booknumber = 1
  End If
  
  GetNextBookN = rst!booknumber
  rst!booknumber = rst!booknumber + 1
  rst.Update
  rst.Close
  
End Function
```

***Update:
The poster was using vb.net, not VBA, my bad.
Here is the above as vb.net, it really much the same.***

```
Public Function GetNextBookN(strBookType As String) As Integer

    Using mycon As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString1)

        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblBookIncrement where BookType = '" & strBookType & "'"
        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, mycon)
            Dim cmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            Dim rst As New DataTable
            da.Fill(rst)
            da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True
            With rst
                If .Rows.Count = 0 Then
                    With .Rows.Add
                        .Item("BookType") = strBookType
                        .Item("booknumber") = 1
                    End With
                    GetNextBookN = 1
                Else
                    GetNextBookN = .Rows(0).Item("booknumber")
                    .Rows(0).Item("booknumber") += 1
                End If
            End With
            da.Update(rst)
        End Using

    End Using

End Function
```

So, now anytime you need a book number, you can go like this:

Say, in a form, you need to assign the book number, you could go like this:

You could say use the on-insert event of the form, and go like this:

```
me!BookNumber = me!bookType & GetNextBookN(me!bookType)
```

So, the above would say if the bookType is "P", result in P101 if the numbering table has a book type of P and the booknumber set to 101. And of course once you pull that number, then the handy dandy function will increment the number for you.

And I also added the feature that if the type requested does not exist, then we add the type and start at 1. This way, the code works as you over time add new types of books, and then the book number table will always work, and have available a next book number easily available in code.

Comment: DAO? Recordset? on-insert event of the form? Is this vb.net? That is what the question is tagged.

Comment: Ah, I did miss that! - I will correct this!!! (thank you)

Comment: The answer below also mentions access - so either tags or the message was changed - but regardless, I have posted the code in both VBA and vb.net now. And to really cook ones noodle? Well you can use + reference the DAO object model in vb.net, so the DAO code could work as posted.  But as noted, I posted both VBA and a vb.net code example.

Answer (score 2):

I see several problems with your fundamental numbering strategy.

1. Most library numbering systems (Dewey Decimal/Library of Congress) factor sort ordering abilities to their numbering system and allow for future additions to be able to sort higher without needing to shift the number of all other items. With your incremental strategy, how would you accommodate inserting a book later in the process?
2. If you set up with three digits of numbering, what would you do once you get 1000 books in a category?
3. While you could use a magic number table that includes the last id allocated per category and increment it as you add a new book. If you have more than one user, there is a potential for a race condition where two users get the same last number and both try to increment it at the same time landing on the same new Id.

I typically recommend keeping a generic ID that has no meaning in the system. This number would be set as an Auto Number in Access and the database would generate new Ids when records are added and ensure that you don't have the collision issue above. If you absolutely need a publically viewable Id, you can use the magic number strategy for a separate BookNumber column that isn't used for record identity. That way if you have a collision in the future, data won't get corrupted.

Comment: Actually i am creating this software for school which has very small library. This sort numbering strategy is asked by school to add in this software. I pointed the same issue of number of books increasing more than 1000 books but they simply said it is never gonna happen. So if you can help me to apply this type of numbering strategy, it would be very helpful. Thank you for you answer